# How do you style/modify the dragged element of a header component?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using ag-grid-react 22.1.1 and ag-grid-community 22.1.1.

I want to style the element that shows up when you try to re-order the columns of a table. In addition, is it possible to change the data passed into the dragged component? As far as I can tell it's always the display name.

[Image of component I want to style/modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrp3u.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/wEonbfGUwxhu7hOGWSDx?p=preview

> I want to style the element that shows up when you try to re-order the columns of a table.

When you drag any column, the `div.ag-dnd-host` gets added as the last element of the body. You can apply style to that guy.

```
.ag-dnd-ghost {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

[image]

> Is it possible to change the data passed into the dragged component? As far as I can tell it's always the display name.

You are right, AFAIK, it's not possible to change the data passed here.

Comment: Are there ways to change the composition then? Or is the only option to use CSS to override the existing styling?

Comment: CSS is the only option.